# Asp.Net Core 2.0 Subdomain Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to map routes to a controller action while passing a parameter as the subdomain, e.g http://subdomain.mydomain.com where "subdomain" is a parameter I'll be passing to the controller action for a database lookup. Is this achievable with Asp.Net Core 2.0 and how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Area which is a feature used to organize related functionality into a group as a separate routing-namespace for controller actions and folder structure for views.

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "areaRoute",
     template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

This code is an example of a custom route for Area.
Maybe this link would help you [Areas in ASP .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Thanks @Llazar, I already have routing set up for my areas. What I'm trying to do is pass the subdomain name as a parameter to the Index action of the HomeController in my Area (which is named "Subdomains", for example)..

Comment: I think routedata by default uses the URL path only. You might be able to add the subdomain to the request routedata with a custom middleware.